# Solving a PDE that looks like Kinetic Fokker Planck without diffusion

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

I am interested to solve the following PDE .
$$\partial_t f(t,x,y)=-y\partial_xf(t,x,y)+(x+y)\partial_y f(t,x,y)+\alpha f(t,x,y)$$
with $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

This reminds me kinetic fokker planck without the diffusion term in $y$ and under harmonic potential in both $x$ and $y$.

I tried with characterist method but I think I have too many variables and I was not able to conclude.

How can I solve it (if possible?). Is there a method I am not aware of?

Comment: Method of characteristics works here, but determining which characteristic curve a general point $(t,x,y)$ lies on takes some doing.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*. Let $f(x,y,t)=u(\xi,\eta,t)$, where $\xi:=x^2+y^2+xy$ and $\eta:=\frac{y}{x}$. Show that
$$
-yf_x+(x+y)f_y=\xi u_{\xi}+(\eta^2+\eta+1)u_{\eta}. \tag{1}
$$
Expressed in terms of the new coordinates, the PDE becomes
$$
u_t=\xi u_{\xi}+(\eta^2+\eta+1)u_{\eta}+\alpha u, \tag{2}
$$
for which the Lagrange-Charpit equations are separable.